# How do I merge multiple tables into a new table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, merge

I'm pretty new to SQL and I have 12 tables with the same schema containing the same types of data from 12 months, and I need to merge them all into one big table. How can I do this in BigQuery using SQL?

I have tried creating a temp table, which is all well and good, but I want to be able to come back to it later.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586195/bigquery-using-insert-into-to-copy-data-from-one-nested-table-into-another-nes. And `union all` tables

Comment: Is there not a more efficient way? I would have to write out that level of specificity for each column heading for 12 tables, right? Every table contains identical columns.

Comment: No, your new table has as many columns as the rest you write `select * from ` and the insert  does not need any column names, the link provided you with the general idea the rest you need to research

Comment: Several tables can be quered at once using a `*` in the table name. This wildcard tables feature is described here: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.